# Notation question. Piecewise function.

Tags: notation

I have observed the below statement in a report.

> $
>    f(x,y) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        f<0 & : (x,y) \in A\\
>        f = 0 & : (x,y) \in B \\
>        f>0 & : (x,y) \in C
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$

I understand the meaning behind it, but is the notation correct? And in this case how do I write the statement then?

Comment: $=$ means "is equal to". So you are saying that $f(x,y)$ is equal to "$f$ is less than $0$" when $(x,y)$ is in $A$, that $f(x,y)$ is equal to "$f$ is equal to $0$" when $(x,y)$ is in $B$, and that $f(x,y)$ is equal to "$f$ is greater than $0$" when $(x,y)\in C$. I would say that one can divine your intent, but it's lousy notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s at best confusing: I’m not entirely certain what is intended. If the intended meaning is that $f(x,y)$ is negative on $A$, $0$ on $B$, and positive on $C$, you could use the [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) and write

$$\operatorname{sgn}\big(f(x,y)\big)=\begin{cases}-1,&\text{if }(x,y)\in A\\
0,&\text{if }(x,y)\in B\\
1,&\text{if }(x,y)\in C\;.
\end{cases}$$

And if that’s the intended meaning, I don’t consider what’s in the report correct, though others may be more generous than I.

Answer (score 2):

No, the notation is not correct, as in its present form it says things like $$f(x,y)=f<0.$$
I would have expressed this more simply as $$f(x,y)<0, \mbox{ for } (x,y)\in A,$$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to stay as close as possible to what you quoted, but not to write nonsense, the best I can do is 
$$
f(x,y)\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       <0 & : (x,y) \in A\\
        = 0 & : (x,y) \in B \\
       >0 & : (x,y) \in C
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
(In "real life" I'd uses LaTeX's "cases" environment, but that doesn't seem to work here.)